# Kakao test navigation drawer

Tags: android-testing

Does anyone know how to test the navigation drawer with Kakao? I have simple activity and 2 fragments. I use Jetpack navigation components and want to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class FormScreen : Screen<FormScreen>() {
val drawerLayout = KView { withId(R.id.drawer_layout) }
val navigationView = KNavigationView { withId(R.id.nav_view) }
val textKK = KTextView { withId(R.id.text_home) }
val fromTV = KTextView { withId(R.id.progressBar2) }
}

  @Test
  fun drawNavigationFromTasksToStatistics() {
    // start up Tasks screen
    val activityScenario = ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity::class.java)
    dataBindingIdlingResource.monitorActivity(activityScenario)

    onScreen<FormScreen>{
        drawerLayout{
            perform {
                navigateTo(R.id.nav_home)
            }
        }
        textKK.isDisplayed()

    }
```